# How can i input some music in my html code?

Tags: html

Im new here and also i'm a student from university of Kavala. I was starting learning about codes such us html and css and i was wondering how can i input some music in my html code, so when i open my index it will show up my html site with some music.

Answer (score 1):

audio tags are supported since HTML 4.0. Try this:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="abc.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="xyz.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support audio.
</audio>
```